# In ServiceStack how can i use an externally issued JWT

Tags: c#, servicestack, jwt, claims-based-identity

I'm working in c# on .net/mono on an IOT type project with devices and a cloud service. The cloud services handle authentication and claims using IdentityServer3 and I have it successfully providing a token with claims.

The device will not have an internet connection when a user attempt to interact with it so a JWT token may be aquired taken from the cloud and passed to an entirely disconnected system. The signing key for the JWT is preshared at provisioning so it will be able to verify the integrity of the token.

In servicestack there is support of JWT but I can't find out how to pass a JWT token with the request in a way which populates the AuthSession. Can anyone provide guidance on:

1. How do I configure the ServiceStack to identify validate and unpack the JWT contents without being the issuer? I can't find any examples like this. I've tried JsonClient .BearerToken and .SetTokenCookie to no avail.
2. If 1 isn't currently possible can I hook into the extensibility points provided to create the functionality required, and if so can you direct me where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst ServiceStack includes it's own JWT Auth Provider, you should be using the same library that issues token to handle it in ServiceStack. So only use ServiceStack's built-in JWT AuthProvider if it's also being used to create the token.

If you're using IdentifyServer instead, you can checkout this project:

https://github.com/MacLeanElectrical/servicestack-authentication-identityserver/

Or this guide:

http://estynedwards.com/blog/2016/01/30/ServiceStack-IdentityServer-Angular/

For examples of how to process IdentifyServer issued tokens.